# Not able to login with username and password for chat in Xmpp

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm trying to implement chat using Xmpp Framework i have imported the framework successfully and i have  connected server also my problem is I'm not able to login the username and password which i have created in server. I'm using Open Fire for xmpp chat their i have created user's but I'm not able login.

MY CODE

```
- (void)setupStream {

xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

xmppStream.hostName=@"Hostname";
//xmppStream.hostPort=5222;


   }

- (void)goOnline {
     XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
     [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
  }

- (void)goOffline {
     XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];
     [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
 }


- (void)disconnect {
     [self goOffline];
     [xmppStream disconnect];
  }

- (BOOL)connect {

     [self setupStream];

     NSString *jabberID = @"test12";
     NSString *myPassword = @"1234567";

  if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
    return YES;
   }


  if (jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil) {

      return NO;
   }

  [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
  //    password = myPassword;

   NSError *error = nil;
  if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
   {
       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];


        return NO;
    } 
   else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection success");
        return YES;
     }


     return YES;
   }
```

xmppStream code

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    NSError *error = nil;
    [[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:@"1234567" error:&error];

 }


- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {

    [self goOnline];

  }


- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq {

     return NO;

    }
```

i have done like above code im getting connection seccuss but user not able  to login  im getting like .

```
 Connection success
<?xml version='1.0'?>
 <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='app.umeetup.com'>
 <stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="app.umeetup.com" id="9da175a8" stream1:lang="en" version="1.0"/>
RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
 SEND: <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="DIGEST-MD5"/>
  RECV: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cmVhbG09ImFwcC51bWVldHVwLmNvbSIsbm9uY2U9IjBSYm13alFDRkplVHNBQXhXdm9DekppQXg2aUM1aXRiYmZHMERiV0QiLHFvcD0iYXV0aCIsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCxhbGdvcml0aG09bWQ1LXNlc3M=</challenge>
  SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dXNlcm5hbWU9InRlc3QxMiIscmVhbG09ImFwcC51bWVldHVwLmNvbSIsbm9uY2U9IjBSYm13alFDRkplVHNBQXhXdm9DekppQXg2aUM1aXRiYmZHMERiV0QiLGNub25jZT0iQzNEQzc2NTAtRTREOS00QTBGLUEzQjQtNUEzM0NBQzZEQzBFIixuYz0wMDAwMDAwMSxxb3A9YXV0aCxkaWdlc3QtdXJpPSJ4bXBwL2FwcC51bWVldHVwLmNvbSIscmVzcG9uc2U9ZjEyNjgxN2ViYWIxZGExZGY5ZmE5MmVjMmNjY2QwYjgsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOA==</response>
RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```

please someone guide to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send entire jabber id while doing login :

```
 NSString *jabberID = @"test12";
```

This should be something like this

```
  NSString *jabberID = @"test12@yourdomain.com";
```

If you are working on localhost it should be as below :

```
 NSString *jabberID = @"test12@localhost";
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to get `not-authorized` because of you **jabberID** type. It must look like email, not only login part but domain too.

Try using:

```
*jabberID = @"test12@my.domain";
```